# Swift 3 - Esperar el resultado del servidor

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Como podría esperar a que el servidor me devuelva un resultado y solo después ejecutar otra función (la cual usará datos de la respuesta del servidor).

Algo como:

- func A: obtengo respuesta del servidor: responseCode = 200, que almaceno en una variable "code"
- func B: comprueba si la variable "code" es 200.

No logro encontrar la manera y hasta el momento siempre ejecuta la func B antes de que func A acabe.

Muchas gracias.

Hasta ahora he intentado lo siguiente:

```
    @IBAction private func bt_signin () {
        print("Paso 1")
        func_a(text: url_text)
        func_b()
    }


private func func_a(text: String) {

    print("Paso 2")

    let url = NSURL(string: text)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else
        {
            print("Error: ", error)
            return
        }

        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
        {
            self.responseCode = httpStatus!.statusCode
            print("Paso 3")                
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func func_b (){
    print("Paso 4")
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        print("Paso 5")
    }
}
```

Y por pantalla obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Paso 1
Paso 2
Paso 4
Paso 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar closures. [Documentación de Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Un ejemplo tomando tu codigo y ejecutado en un playground:

```
func do_a(text: String, completion: (Void) -> Void) {
  print("Paso 1")
  // tu codigo
  print("Paso 2")
  // tu codigo
  print("Paso 3")
  // tu codigo
  completion() // Ejecutas el closure
}

func do_b(){
  print("Paso 4")
  // tu codigo
  print("Paso 5")
}

do_a(text: "Hola", completion: { do_b() })

// Resultado
// Paso 1
// Paso 2
// Paso 3
// Paso 4
// Paso 5
```

Basicamente la primera función recibe la segunda función como parámetro.